# creating header with axis2 java2wsdl - how?

Tags: java, web-services, header, wsdl, apache-axis

I am using org.apache.axis2 to create wsdl. Our code is implementing ScemaGenerator and has our additions. I am trying to find a way to create the wsdl with the header definition, that will include userName and password.  How can I do that through the code and not through file editing after it was created?  and If I have no choice and I need to edit the file, what is the correct sintax to do it?  What I wrote is creating a wsdl parsing error when it is used for wsdl2Java.  My code:

```
  <wsdl:message name="wsDirectLoginRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:wsDirectLogin">
    </wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part name="request_header" element="intf:pswd">
  </wsdl:message>
...
  <wsdl:input message="ns:wsDirectLoginRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:wsDirectLogin">
   <wsdlsoap:header message="intf:wsDirectLoginRequest" part="request_header" use="literal"/>
       <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:input>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your header representing? You mention a username and password so is it a custom authentication mechanism or a standard WS-Security UsernameToken or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the DefaultSchemaGenerator comes with Axis2.

What is the wsdl error you get? Please look at here for a correct wsdl[1].

But as pointed out in a earlier comment, it is better to thing whether you need to use WS-Security (using rampart) or add headers manually.

[1] http://wso2.org/node/2935/